# Changing equality to something else on SQL command

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am working on a windows form application. I want to change the SQL command by user selection. Here is my code:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE price = @price";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 35);
```

I also want to change "=" to ">=" or something else. When I use parameters for that, I get errors.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Urun WHERE price @equal @price";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 35);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@equal", ">=");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: "I am working on a windows form application." If possible, use WPF instead. It's far better.

Comment: @TimS. It's very well possible that it's an existent application that's being maintained.  There's also the possibility that some people might not be familiar with WPF and might instead go with what they're familiar with.

Comment: Of course, hence the "If possible".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that I generally accomplish this is using `string.format()`.

For example:

```
command.CommandText = string.format("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE price {0} @price", ">=");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 35);
```

In practical use, you'd replace ">=" with the variable that contains your desired operator, such as:

```
string op = ">=";
command.CommandText = string.format("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE price {0} @price", op);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 35);
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Tim S. in the coments, it's not a good idea to have this fed directly in by user input. Personally, I would do this from an enum, and use user input to determine which enum value to use. If you do decide to use direct user input, make sure to scrub the input to avoid possible SQL injection.

Comment: Just make sure the values come from a hardcoded whitelist, *not* just user input. Otherwise [little bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) will ruin your DB.

Answer (score 6):

You can't, basically. Parameterized SQL is just for values - not table names, column names, or operators. This is one place where you *do* probably want to build the SQL dynamically - but with a white-listed set of options.

Whether you build the full SQL up dynamically from bits, or whether you have a set of pre-canned complete SQL queries, will depend on exactly what you're trying to do. And obviously you should still use parameters for the values.

Comment: I'd assume the OP only has a handful of possible operators, in which case a simple "if" or "switch" statement on the CommandText property will do the job.

Comment: I see, so there is no way to do this dynamically, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
string comparation=">="
command.CommandText =string.Format("SELECT * FROM Urun WHERE price {0} @price",comparation);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 35);
```